# How to lay image over another image where the middle of the image should align with the bottom of the image underneath

Tags: android, imageview, layoutparams

I have a banner that I am displaying on an Android Layout. On this banner, I have two avatars that I would like to display next to each other, and most importantly, I would like to have them displayed where **the midway point of these two avatars on the y-axis is aligned with the bottom of the banner that these avatars sit on top of.**

How would you do this?

Edit:

In other words, I'm asking how you could use an parameter like android:layout_below, but instead of it aligning the top of the imageview with the botton of the specified layout, to align the center.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no direct layout parameter to align a center point with another edge.  If the height of your avatars is fixed, you could add some padding that is half the height so they all line up; i.e.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/banner"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingBottom="25dp"
        android:src="@drawable/banner" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/avatar1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@id/banner"
        android:src="@drawable/horse" /> 
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/avatar2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@id/banner"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/avatar1"
        android:src="@drawable/horse" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

If the heights of those items, however, is dynamic, then you will need to create a custom `ViewGroup` container so you can measure the avatar heights (in `onMeasure()`) and apply the padding (or other offset value) at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

Put them in a linear layout, and then give them a width to fill the parent. Then you can use the weight property to disperse the widths equally.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:src="@drawable/clock" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:src="@drawable/clock" />

</LinearLayout>
```